# matlab 3 equations result problems

Tags: matlab

I am not good at matlab but I have to write short programs for my exams, so I started to prepare.

[3 equations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kaMWn.png) So these must be solved with f solve and I have to display the result of these, but this time I have to start from the origo.

[image]

My code is:

```
 x = fsolve(y,x)
function y = t(x)
y=zeros(3,1);
x=ones(3,1);
y(1)=x(1).^3-11*x(1)+x(2).^2+9;
y(2)=x(1)*x(2).^2+x(2)-10*x(1)-11*x(3);
y(3)=x(1)*x(2)+x(3).^4-10*x(2)+8;
end
```

So as I think my refering of the function is bad. I hope it is and no more mistake in it. The error is: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLaIY.jpg
Could you help me out?
Thanking you in advance and have a good health all of you!

Comment: I want the result of the equation. So I need the value of x1,x2,x3.

Comment: an error message beause of the first line.

Comment: Sorry I am back. https://imgur.com/a/Slbi1tV

Comment: Is that the whole error message? Why does the error message show `fsolve(y,t(x))` when your code is `fsolve(y,x)`?

Comment: Harry, the same error message. You mean this? https://imgur.com/a/Z8DwF39

Comment: You have now shown two screenshots with different error messages, and neither of them match the code that you have in the question.

Comment: Yeah I tried modify as Harry said without succes.

Comment: Harry did not tell you to modify anything.

Comment: Yeah I am sorry, I misunderstood you have right. But there is no differance in the result and the error message as well.